# Lights/Lamps not illuminating anything

Tags: light

Right, so I recorded a video, tracked it, set the ground planes etc. And made a cube. The cube renders, but its solid gray, and lighting effects just dont work. I am extremely novice to blender, so its probably just a stupid mistake. Essentially the cube appears a solid gray, green or whatever color I set it to on all sides when rendering, with no tone differences at all. Also, and this might be the problem, I have a cube on a ground layer set up like this:
[image]

This is what it looks like before and after render:
[image]
[image]

Also for additional Info, here are my settings:

[image]
[image]

My .blend: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgDIjhDOu6EY2FOdzNSUVdrTjg/view?usp=sharing
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make the question dependent on downloading a file only. Please take the time to describe what you've done and add images that show your scene and settings. That way if the link to the file disappears, others can still learn from your question.

Comment: ^Alright thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: @JoshSilveous It would be useful if you could make the changes cegaton suggested *this time*. The reason for this is that if people find this question via google they will be able to understand whether they are having a similar issue to yours and whether the answer below will be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have layer one enabled for rendering, and your lamp and plane are on layer 6. To fix this, go to the *render layers* tab, and select both layers while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> that you want to render together, and you shouldn't have any problems.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

well the cube and plane don't have a material also just changing the it from blender render to cycles render makes the shading right this means you have probably ticked some boxes unknowingly can't figure out which ones but just changing it to cycles engine worked.
[image]